# Can I map a folder used by an app in flatpak format to a folder on the OS?

Tags: flatpak

Can I map a folder used by an app in flatpak format to a folder on the OS ?

In the sandboxed app I have the folder `/folder_name/example.txt`.

I want to map this on OS to `/flatpak/config/app_name/example.txt`.
So,  when the app tries to read/modify `/folder_name/example.txt` to actually do it for `/flatpak/config/app_name/example.txt`.

I can give access to the real `folder_name`, and in the real `folder_name` folder to create a symlink to the actual location, but becomes to complicated if there are more files, so I'm looking to see if this is possible from flatpak app configuration.

Comment: At `/home` there should be users' folders, nothing else.

Comment: I used `/home` just as an example, can be any folder. I edited to not create confusion.